# Why do I get a StackOverflowError when sending a Plotly figure to a Dash app?

Tags: julia, plotly-dash

Adapting the second example from https://dash-julia.plotly.com/getting-started as shown below, I get a StackOverflowError. Is the example not up to date or is there something wrong with my code or installation?

Note that adding the figure as a tuple of data works (commented out in the code sample), but using the PlotlyJS.SyncPlot struct returned from plot does not. I can also display the figure in VSCode without any issues.

```
using DataFrames, PlotlyJS
using Dash, DashHtmlComponents, DashCoreComponents
using Random

ydata = [rand() for i in 1:4]

app = dash()

app.layout = html_div() do
    dcc_graph(
        id="example-graph",
        # figure = (data = [(y = ydata,)],)   # Works
        figure = plot(ydata)  # Does not work
    )
end

run_server(app, "0.0.0.0", debug=true)
```

Here is the stacktrace as requested:

```
┌ Error: error handling request
│   exception =
│    StackOverflowError:
│    Stacktrace:
│         [1] (::JSON2.var"#3#4"{DataType})(x::Vector{Any})
│           @ JSON2 C:\Users\Martin\.julia\packages\JSON2\ld4Kq\src\write.jl:11
│         [2] macro expansion
│           @ C:\Users\Martin\.julia\packages\JSON2\ld4Kq\src\write.jl:75 [inlined]
│         [3] write(io::IOBuffer, obj::Observables.Observable{Dict{Any, Any}}; kwargs::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{}, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}})
│           @ JSON2 C:\Users\Martin\.julia\packages\JSON2\ld4Kq\src\write.jl:94
│         [4] write
│           @ C:\Users\Martin\.julia\packages\JSON2\ld4Kq\src\write.jl:94 [inlined]
│         [5] write(io::IOBuffer, obj::Tuple{Observables.Observable{Dict{Any, Any}}, Nothing}; kwargs::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{}, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}})
│           @ JSON2 C:\Users\Martin\.julia\packages\JSON2\ld4Kq\src\write.jl:39
│         [6] write(io::IOBuffer, obj::Tuple{Observables.Observable{Dict{Any, Any}}, Nothing})
│           @ JSON2 C:\Users\Martin\.julia\packages\JSON2\ld4Kq\src\write.jl:35
│         [7] write(io::IOBuffer, obj::Dict{String, Tuple{Observables.AbstractObservable, Union{Nothing, Bool}}}; kwargs::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{}, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}})
│           @ JSON2 C:\Users\Martin\.julia\packages\JSON2\ld4Kq\src\write.jl:24
│         [8] write(io::IOBuffer, obj::Dict{String, Tuple{Observables.AbstractObservable, Union{Nothing, Bool}}})
│           @ JSON2 C:\Users\Martin\.julia\packages\JSON2\ld4Kq\src\write.jl:17
│         [9] macro expansion
│           @ C:\Users\Martin\.julia\packages\JSON2\ld4Kq\src\write.jl:75 [inlined]
│        [10] write(io::IOBuffer, obj::WebIO.Scope; kwargs::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{}, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}})
│           @ JSON2 C:\Users\Martin\.julia\packages\JSON2\ld4Kq\src\write.jl:94
│        [11] write(io::IOBuffer, obj::WebIO.Scope)
│           @ JSON2 C:\Users\Martin\.julia\packages\JSON2\ld4Kq\src\write.jl:94
│    --- the last 3 lines are repeated 1 more time ---
│        [15] write(io::IOBuffer, obj::Vector{Any}; kwargs::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{}, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}})
│           @ JSON2 C:\Users\Martin\.julia\packages\JSON2\ld4Kq\src\write.jl:39
│        [16] write(io::IOBuffer, obj::Vector{Any})
│           @ JSON2 C:\Users\Martin\.julia\packages\JSON2\ld4Kq\src\write.jl:35
│    --- the last 15 lines are repeated 2208 more times ---
│     [33137] macro expansion
│           @ C:\Users\Martin\.julia\packages\JSON2\ld4Kq\src\write.jl:75 [inlined]
│     [33138] write(io::IOBuffer, obj::Observables.Observable{Dict{Any, Any}}; kwargs::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{}, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}})
│           @ JSON2 C:\Users\Martin\.julia\packages\JSON2\ld4Kq\src\write.jl:94
│     [33139] write
│           @ C:\Users\Martin\.julia\packages\JSON2\ld4Kq\src\write.jl:94 [inlined]
│     [33140] write(io::IOBuffer, obj::Tuple{Observables.Observable{Dict{Any, Any}}, Nothing}; kwargs::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{}, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}})
│           @ JSON2 C:\Users\Martin\.julia\packages\JSON2\ld4Kq\src\write.jl:39
│     [33141] write(io::IOBuffer, obj::Tuple{Observables.Observable{Dict{Any, Any}}, Nothing})
│           @ JSON2 C:\Users\Martin\.julia\packages\JSON2\ld4Kq\src\write.jl:35
│     [33142] write(io::IOBuffer, obj::Dict{String, Tuple{Observables.AbstractObservable, Union{Nothing, Bool}}}; kwargs::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{}, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}})
│           @ JSON2 C:\Users\Martin\.julia\packages\JSON2\ld4Kq\src\write.jl:24
│     [33143] write(io::IOBuffer, obj::Dict{String, Tuple{Observables.AbstractObservable, Union{Nothing, Bool}}})
│           @ JSON2 C:\Users\Martin\.julia\packages\JSON2\ld4Kq\src\write.jl:17
│     [33144] macro expansion
│           @ C:\Users\Martin\.julia\packages\JSON2\ld4Kq\src\write.jl:75 [inlined]
│     [33145] write(io::IOBuffer, obj::WebIO.Scope; kwargs::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{}, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}})
│           @ JSON2 C:\Users\Martin\.julia\packages\JSON2\ld4Kq\src\write.jl:94
│     [33146] write(io::IOBuffer, obj::WebIO.Scope)
│           @ JSON2 C:\Users\Martin\.julia\packages\JSON2\ld4Kq\src\write.jl:94
│    --- the last 3 lines are repeated 1 more time ---
│     [33150] write(io::IOBuffer, obj::Dict{Symbol, Any}; kwargs::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{}, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}})
│           @ JSON2 C:\Users\Martin\.julia\packages\JSON2\ld4Kq\src\write.jl:24
│     [33151] write(io::IOBuffer, obj::Dict{Symbol, Any})
│           @ JSON2 C:\Users\Martin\.julia\packages\JSON2\ld4Kq\src\write.jl:17
│     [33152] macro expansion
│           @ C:\Users\Martin\.julia\packages\JSON2\ld4Kq\src\write.jl:75 [inlined]
│     [33153] macro expansion
│           @ C:\Users\Martin\.julia\packages\JSON2\ld4Kq\src\JSON2.jl:0 [inlined]
│     [33154] write(io::IOBuffer, obj::Component; kwargs::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{}, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}})
│           @ DashBase C:\Users\Martin\.julia\packages\JSON2\ld4Kq\src\JSON2.jl:127
│     [33155] write(io::IOBuffer, obj::Component)
│           @ DashBase C:\Users\Martin\.julia\packages\JSON2\ld4Kq\src\JSON2.jl:127
│     [33156] write(io::IOBuffer, obj::Dict{Symbol, Any}; kwargs::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{}, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}})
│           @ JSON2 C:\Users\Martin\.julia\packages\JSON2\ld4Kq\src\write.jl:24
│     [33157] write(io::IOBuffer, obj::Dict{Symbol, Any})
│           @ JSON2 C:\Users\Martin\.julia\packages\JSON2\ld4Kq\src\write.jl:17
│     [33158] macro expansion
│           @ C:\Users\Martin\.julia\packages\JSON2\ld4Kq\src\write.jl:75 [inlined]
│     [33159] macro expansion
│           @ C:\Users\Martin\.julia\packages\JSON2\ld4Kq\src\JSON2.jl:0 [inlined]
│     [33160] write(io::IOBuffer, obj::Component; kwargs::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{}, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}})
│           @ DashBase C:\Users\Martin\.julia\packages\JSON2\ld4Kq\src\JSON2.jl:127
│     [33161] write
│           @ C:\Users\Martin\.julia\packages\JSON2\ld4Kq\src\JSON2.jl:127 [inlined]
│     [33162] #write#5
│           @ C:\Users\Martin\.julia\packages\JSON2\ld4Kq\src\write.jl:14 [inlined]
│     [33163] write(obj::Component)
│           @ JSON2 C:\Users\Martin\.julia\packages\JSON2\ld4Kq\src\write.jl:14
│     [33164] process_layout(request::HTTP.Messages.Request, state::Dash.HandlerState)
│           @ Dash C:\Users\Martin\.julia\packages\Dash\66VCI\src\handler\processors\layout.jl:4
│     [33165] try_handle
│           @ C:\Users\Martin\.julia\packages\Dash\66VCI\src\HttpHelpers\router.jl:51 [inlined]
│     [33166] try_handle(route::Dash.HttpHelpers.Route{Dash.HttpHelpers.RouteHandler{Dash.HttpHelpers.StaticRoute, typeof(Dash.process_layout)}}, path::SubString{String}, request::HTTP.Messages.Request, args::Dash.HandlerState)
│           @ Dash.HttpHelpers C:\Users\Martin\.julia\packages\Dash\66VCI\src\HttpHelpers\router.jl:97
│     [33167] _handle
│           @ C:\Users\Martin\.julia\packages\Dash\66VCI\src\HttpHelpers\router.jl:101 [inlined]
│     [33168] handle(route_tuple::Tuple{Dash.HttpHelpers.Route{Dash.HttpHelpers.RouteHandler{Dash.HttpHelpers.StaticRoute, typeof(Dash.process_layout)}}, Dash.HttpHelpers.Route{Dash.HttpHelpers.RouteHandler{Dash.HttpHelpers.StaticRoute, typeof(Dash.process_dependencies)}}, Dash.HttpHelpers.Route{Dash.HttpHelpers.RouteHandler{Dash.HttpHelpers.StaticRoute, typeof(Dash.process_reload_hash)}}, Dash.HttpHelpers.Route{Dash.HttpHelpers.RouteHandler{Dash.HttpHelpers.DynamicRoute{Tuple{Tuple{Int64, String}}, NamedTuple{(:path, :namespace), Tuple{Int64, Int64}}}, typeof(Dash.process_resource)}}, Dash.HttpHelpers.Route{Dash.HttpHelpers.RouteHandler{Dash.HttpHelpers.DynamicRoute{Tuple{Tuple{Int64, String}}, NamedTuple{(:file_path,), Tuple{Int64}}}, typeof(Dash.process_assets)}}, Dash.HttpHelpers.Route{Dash.HttpHelpers.RouteHandler{Dash.HttpHelpers.StaticRoute, typeof(Dash.process_callback)}}, Dash.HttpHelpers.Route{Dash.HttpHelpers.RouteHandler{Dash.HttpHelpers.DynamicRoute{Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}}, typeof(Dash.process_index)}}, Dash.HttpHelpers.Route{Dash.HttpHelpers.RouteHandler{Dash.HttpHelpers.StaticRoute, typeof(Dash.process_index)}}}, path::SubString{String}, request::HTTP.Messages.Request, args::Dash.HandlerState)     
│           @ Dash.HttpHelpers C:\Users\Martin\.julia\packages\Dash\66VCI\src\HttpHelpers\router.jl:112
│     [33169] handle(router::Dash.HttpHelpers.Router, request::HTTP.Messages.Request, args::Dash.HandlerState)
│           @ Dash.HttpHelpers C:\Users\Martin\.julia\packages\Dash\66VCI\src\HttpHelpers\router.jl:129
│     [33170] (::Dash.HttpHelpers.var"#1#2"{Dash.HttpHelpers.Router, Dash.HandlerState})(::HTTP.Messages.Request)
│           @ Dash.HttpHelpers C:\Users\Martin\.julia\packages\Dash\66VCI\src\HttpHelpers\handlers.jl:4
│     [33171] handle
│           @ C:\Users\Martin\.julia\packages\HTTP\5e2VH\src\Handlers.jl:254 [inlined]
│     [33172] (::Dash.HttpHelpers.var"#7#8"{Dash.var"#71#73"{Dash.DashApp}, HTTP.Handlers.RequestHandlerFunction{Dash.HttpHelpers.var"#1#2"{Dash.HttpHelpers.Router, Dash.HandlerState}}})(::HTTP.Messages.Request)
│           @ Dash.HttpHelpers C:\Users\Martin\.julia\packages\Dash\66VCI\src\HttpHelpers\handlers.jl:48
│     [33173] handle
│           @ C:\Users\Martin\.julia\packages\HTTP\5e2VH\src\Handlers.jl:254 [inlined]
│     [33174] (::Dash.HttpHelpers.var"#4#5"{Vector{String}, Int64, HTTP.Handlers.RequestHandlerFunction{Dash.HttpHelpers.var"#7#8"{Dash.var"#71#73"{Dash.DashApp}, HTTP.Handlers.RequestHandlerFunction{Dash.HttpHelpers.var"#1#2"{Dash.HttpHelpers.Router, Dash.HandlerState}}}}})(::HTTP.Messages.Request)
│           @ Dash.HttpHelpers C:\Users\Martin\.julia\packages\Dash\66VCI\src\HttpHelpers\handlers.jl:27
│     [33175] handle
│           @ C:\Users\Martin\.julia\packages\HTTP\5e2VH\src\Handlers.jl:254 [inlined]
│     [33176] handle(::HTTP.Handlers.RequestHandlerFunction{Dash.HttpHelpers.var"#4#5"{Vector{String}, Int64, HTTP.Handlers.RequestHandlerFunction{Dash.HttpHelpers.var"#7#8"{Dash.var"#71#73"{Dash.DashApp}, HTTP.Handlers.RequestHandlerFunction{Dash.HttpHelpers.var"#1#2"{Dash.HttpHelpers.Router, Dash.HandlerState}}}}}}, ::HTTP.Streams.Stream{HTTP.Messages.Request, HTTP.ConnectionPool.Transaction{Sockets.TCPSocket}})
│           @ HTTP.Handlers C:\Users\Martin\.julia\packages\HTTP\5e2VH\src\Handlers.jl:277
│     [33177] #4
│           @ C:\Users\Martin\.julia\packages\HTTP\5e2VH\src\Handlers.jl:346 [inlined]
│     [33178] macro expansion
│           @ C:\Users\Martin\.julia\packages\HTTP\5e2VH\src\Servers.jl:413 [inlined]
└ @ Dash C:\Users\Martin\.julia\packages\Dash\66VCI\src\handler\make_handler.jl:110
```

Comment: Can you add the error output to your question?

Comment: Done, thank you for having a look.

Comment: Don't know, It works to me so I can't really trace down what goes wrong. I guess you already checked it, but anyway make sure your packages are up to date. And could it be that the `plot` function also has been imported from some other package causing the wanted function not being called at all?

Comment: Knowing that the code is fine is a big help. Even after re-installing Julia I still get the same error unfortunately. The plot function seems to be working correctly and I can display the figure in vscode.